# Send an Email on IOS Platform

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, email, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to add email capability to my IOS project made with Xamarin Forms. I'm using DependencyService to implement the email function and my IOS code is as follows:

```
public void SendEmail(string[] recipients, string subject, string body, string filePath, string fileName)
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController mailController;

        if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
        {
            mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();

            mailController.SetToRecipients(recipients);
            mailController.SetSubject(subject);
            mailController.SetMessageBody(body, false);
            mailController.AddAttachmentData(NSData.FromFile(filePath), "application/pdf", fileName);
            mailController.Finished += (object s, MFComposeResultEventArgs args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args.Result.ToString());
                args.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
            };

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
        }
    }
```

but when I test the implementation, nothing happens no errors or anything. I can continue to use the app as normal after the failed attempt to email. I understand this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368654/xamarin-ios-how-to-send-emails) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694998/sending-email-in-xamarin-forms?rq=1) but I have already enabled an email account on my testing iPad's default mail app and have removed all instances of DisplayActionSheet in my PCL implementation.

Comment: have you used the debugger to verify that this code is being executed?

Comment: @Jason I always put a DisplayAlert at the end when testing code to ensure that it executes.